# F# how to specify type restriction in recursive discriminated unions

Tags: f#, restriction, f#-3.0

I am trying to define my grammar as a discriminated union. It has two possible types: `int` and `datetime` and mathemetical operators of `Add` and `Mul`. 
`Add` works on `int` and `datetime` (as add days in int)
`Mul` works only on `int` and not on `datetime`
Grammar can be recursive

My grammar looks like

```
type MyExpression =
|Integer of int
|Date of datetime
|Add of MyExpression * MyExpression
|Mul of MyExpression * MyExpression
```

I have written a parser (fparsec) that can parse text in my grammar, but I am not sure how to handle the condition that `Mul` can be recursive but only on `Integer`.

Is there an option to define this restriction on my `MyExpression` type or do I have to handle this in my parsed input?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The design suggested by Asti would also be my first choice. Depending on your requirements, that may be all you need.

It does, however, also enable you to compile an expression like

```
Add(Val(System.Console.Out), Val(System.Console.Error))
```

which is probably not what you want.

Alternatively, you could model expressions like this:

```
open System

type IntExpression =
| Integer of int
| Mul of IntExpression * IntExpression
| Add of IntExpression * IntExpression

type DateTimeExpression =
| Date of DateTime
| Add of DateTimeExpression * DateTimeExpression

type MyExpression =
| IntExpression of IntExpression
| DateTimeExpression of DateTimeExpression
```

This is clearly a more verbose type definition, but it does embody the rule that an expression can contain leaf nodes of either integers or `DateTime` values, and no other values - if that's the rule you want to enforce.

I'm not claiming that this is better; I'm only supplying an alternative.

Usage:

```
> IntExpression(Mul(IntExpression.Add(Integer(1), Integer(2)),Integer 3));;
val it : MyExpression =
  IntExpression (Mul (Add (Integer 1,Integer 2),Integer 3))
> DateTimeExpression(Add(Date(DateTime.MinValue),Date(DateTime.MinValue)));;
val it : MyExpression =
  DateTimeExpression
    (Add
       (Date 01.01.0001 00:00:00 {Date = 01.01.0001 00:00:00;
                                  Day = 1;
                                  DayOfWeek = Monday;
                                  DayOfYear = 1;
                                  Hour = 0;
                                  Kind = Unspecified;
                                  Millisecond = 0;
                                  Minute = 0;
                                  Month = 1;
                                  Second = 0;
                                  Ticks = 0L;
                                  TimeOfDay = 00:00:00;
                                  Year = 1;},
        Date 01.01.0001 00:00:00 {Date = 01.01.0001 00:00:00;
                                  Day = 1;
                                  DayOfWeek = Monday;
                                  DayOfYear = 1;
                                  Hour = 0;
                                  Kind = Unspecified;
                                  Millisecond = 0;
                                  Minute = 0;
                                  Month = 1;
                                  Second = 0;
                                  Ticks = 0L;
                                  TimeOfDay = 00:00:00;
                                  Year = 1;}))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have type based constraints, it may be easier going for a generic approach:

```
type MyExpression<'t> =
|Val of 't
|Mul of MyExpression<int> * MyExpression<int>
|Add of MyExpression<'t> * MyExpression<'t>

let Integer (x:int) = Val(x)
let Date (x:DateTime) = Val(x)
```

Usage:

```
Mul(Integer(1), Integer(2)) //compiles
Mul(Date(DateTime.Now), Date(DateTime.Now)) //error
```

Comment: This handles some of the restrictions, but not all of them - the following is not a sensible expression, but it type checks: `Add(Date(DateTime.Now), Mul(Integer 1, Integer  2))`